How can I Identify the corresponding table rows in Excel from Bing Maps Complement interaction?
I'm currently using the Bing Maps complement for Excel to locate where some pictures were taken. I have a table with different longitudes and latitudes that I feed to Bing Maps, and the map shows the corresponding dots. All good so far.
Now, when I click on a dot, I'd like to know which picture this dot represents, or in other words, which row in the table I'm using. Is there a way to know which row in my table I am currently looking at?
I can number them and see a number with the tool tip, but that makes every next dot bigger than the other (because Bing assumes it's a value to be displayed).
My ideal scenario is to find a way to put the row number in a cell when I click on a dot on the Bing Map.
Thanks!

Does this answer your question? Returning values from the bing map complement in excel
